# List View com TextView e ImageView

Tags: android, listview

Estou tentando fazer um `ListView` com `TextView` e `ImageView`(obtida através de um URL), quando estava só com `TextView` estava aparecendo normal, mas quando adicionei o código para aparecer as imagens, a tela fica toda branca. Qual poderia ser o problema?
Usei o método `setImageURI()` pra setar o link da imagem.
o codigo que estou usando é seguinte:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    StockQuoteView sqView = null;

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        // Get a new instance of the row layout view
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticia_list_item, null);

        // Hold the view objects in an object,
        // so they don't need to be re-fetched
        sqView = new StockQuoteView();
         //sqView.quote = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_symbol);
        sqView.ticker = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_price);
        sqView.img  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);     
        // Cache the view objects in the tag,
        // so they can be re-accessed later
        rowView.setTag(sqView);
    } else {
        sqView = (StockQuoteView) rowView.getTag();
    }

    // Transfer the stock data from the data object
    // to the view objects
    Noticias currentStock = (Noticias) stocks.get(position);
    sqView.ticker.setText(currentStock.getTitulo());
    sqView.img.setImageURI(currentStock.getImagem());// bom aqui eu pensei que o setImageURI iria setar o link da imagem e assim exibi-la... mas é necessário uma conversão pra bitmap?

  // sqView.quote.setText(currentStock.getDescricao());

    return rowView;
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o código que você está usando que talvez fique mais fácil te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não confunda URL com URI. Você não pode requisitar dados de uma URL, exemplo: `www.meusite.com.br/imagens/imagem.png`, através de `setImageURI()`.

Isto é uma coisa [busca a imagem no seu dispositivo através do caminho dado na URI]:

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("file:///data/data/MINHA_PASTA_ANDROID/minhaimage.png");
imgview.setImageUri(imgUri);
```

E isto é outra coisa [Converte a imagem em Bitmap de uma URL]:

```
private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
   }
   return bm;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado...

Comment: Ajudou? Vote positivo!

Comment: Creio que você quis dizer URL e não ULR, não é?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, eu tenho o link da imagem e estava tentando setar em img,(usando o setImageURI() pra exibir a imagem... isto está errado? eu preciso converter o link pra bitmap pra exibi-la?

Comment: Exatamente. Você precisa converter a imagem em Bitmap. Faça uma outra pergunta que eu lhe respondo como :)

Comment: Isso mesmo, @Mateus.

Comment: Bom se é isso, muito obrigado Rafael, foi de grande ajuda... :)